# Excel Top10 on Already Filtered Data

Tags: excel, filtering

Here is what I do : Excel insert table and make table with these values

```
Year    Value
2010    3
2010    4
2010    5
2010    6
2010    7
2010    8
2010    9
2010    10
2011    11
2011    12
2012    13
2012    14
```

1. I can filter by year=2010
2. I can filter by value : Number Filters, Top 10, Choose Top 5 items
3. But I CAN'T apply both filters. I expect to get Top5 values from 2010.

   But I get Top5 values of all time, then ones not being 2010 removed, I end up with only one row.

What am I doing wrong, how can I do this in Excel ?

Comment: According to the documentation, this is possible with Advanced Filtering (not Custom Filtering), but I'm not having much luck with it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys ! I am closer to the Advanced Filters solution. After you told me about them I was able to find a YouTube tutorial "Mr Excel & excelisfun Trick 8: Top 10 Filter Trouble". It looks like guy explained it in 2 minutes ;-) Talking very fast, I have to pause the video lol